# GWT error: The response could not be deserialized

Tags: java, hibernate, gwt, dto

I have developed several GWT Web Applications. Latest one is a little modification of another one. All of them works well except for the latest one. The exception is:

```
The response could not be deserialized
```

I am using Hibernate and Data Transfer Objects between Hibernate and GWT. Each DTO implements java.io.Serializable interface. As I said before, in other applications works well. Could someone help me with this error? I do not know what the cause is.

My Hibernate object code is:

```
public List<AttributeDTO> getAttributes(){
    String sql = "from Attribute where (select max(tDate) from Attribute)-tDate < '0 days 00:05'";
    List<Attribute> attributes = new ArrayList<Attribute>(DatabaseManager.createQuery(sql));
    List<AttributeDTO> attributeDTOs = new ArrayList<AttributeDTO>(attributes != null ? attributes.size() : 0);
    if (attributes != null) {
        for (Attribute attribute : attributes) {
            String date = format.format(attribute.gettDate());
            attributeDTOs.add(new AttributeDTO(attribute.getiAttrId(),attribute.getsName(),attribute.getsValue(),date,attribute.getiDeviceId(),attribute.getsUnits(),new ApplicationFieldDTO()));
        }
    }
    return attributeDTOs;
}
```

And AttributeDTO is:

```
public class AttributeDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private int iAttrId;
    private String name;
    private String value;
    private String date;
    private String units;
    private int iDeviceId;
    private ApplicationFieldDTO appField;

    public AttributeDTO() {}

    public AttributeDTO(int attrId, String name, String value, String date, int deviceId, String units, ApplicationFieldDTO appField) {
        this.iAttrId = attrId;
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
        this.date = date;
        this.iDeviceId = deviceId;
        this.units = units;
        this.appField = appField;
    }
}
```

From GWT is call getAttributes() method which returns a List of AttributeDTO.

Thanks!!!

Comment: You should post the code of the DTO that's getting you trouble

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error also appears if only one member of your class is not serializable - thus the error also might be in the definition of ApplicationFieldDTO.

By the way, instead of using data transfer objects you also can use [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?page=gwt), then even lazy loading is working. (But in the case of your existing application the introduction of Gilead might be a lot of work.)

Comment: Thank you, it appears interesting. I will study this possibility

Answer (score 0):

use `ArrayList` instead of List and try again

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553593/gwt-jpa-the-response-could-not-be-deserialized).

Comment: `new ApplicationFieldDTO()` maybe this is it? Is this class serialized or has an empty constructor, doesn't use generic types like List???

Comment: ApplicationDTO is another DTO class and the code is: public class ApplicationFieldDTO implements Serializable{ public ApplicationFieldDTO(){} }

Comment: Look at this 
Look at this [post][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553593/gwt-jpa-the-response-could-not-be-deserialized

Answer (score 0):

I had the same trouble. Try to use com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable instead of Serializable. It worked for me and I hope will help to you :)

Comment: At first development I had com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable and afterwards I changed by java.io.Serializable because it does not work. I think that it is not the problem, but thanks for your response

Comment: @JoseHdez Could you attach stack trace of exception to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I also faced a similar issue. In my case on submitting a value from UI, exception

> "GWT error: The response could not be deserialized"

was shown. What I found was that the entire code base was not packed correctly to convert into .war file. I was using Ant Build method for creating **.war** files.

Later I installed a plugin in eclipse and it worked fine for me. I installed the plugin from eclipse market place using this [link](http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3)

Comment: **"http://dl.google.com/eclipse/inst/d2gwt/latest/4.3"** this link needs to be used in eclipse for installing pulgin.